# How to configure options in :terminal (NeoVim)

Tags: neovim, terminal-buffer, options

I've read the help section for term, terminal, termopen, buftype, and I've read several stack questions, but I haven't been able to find a solution for settings options in terminal mode. I know about `tnoremap`, what I want to do is set options, not remap keys.

I tried:

```
" Terminal Buffer
function! TerminalSettings()
    set nonumber
    set mouse=
    set list
endfunction
augroup terminal
    autocmd!
    autocmd TermOpen call TerminalSettings()
augroup END
```

But this had no effect (as far as I could tell). Is this the correct approach incorrectly implemented, or do I need to do something else?

### Update

I tried opening Vim with the config, and it gave me an error:

```
E216: No such group or event: TermOpen call TerminalSettings()
```

Which leads me to believe that NeoVim at least *has* this event, since it opens without any errors.

I also tried using `setlocal` instead of `set`, but no change.

Setting the option manually works `:setlocal nonumber`.

Comment: You _may_ need `setlocal`. FWIW in regular vim even with `set number`, when I run `:terminal` there are never line numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. The approach was correct, it was just a syntax issue:
`autocmd TermOpen * call TerminalSettings()`. I was missing the asterisk.

My current config is now:

```
" Terminal Buffer
function! TerminalSettings()
    setlocal nonumber
    normal a
endfunction
augroup terminal
    autocmd!
    autocmd TermOpen * call TerminalSettings()
augroup END
```

FYI what helped me find it was the Vim documentation 40.3 example `:autocmd FileWritePre *  call DateInsert()` and explanation `:autocmd [group] {events} {file_pattern} [nested] {command}`. I was confused by the `:help autocmd` section which said `{pat}` instead of `{file_pattern}`.

Comment: `{pat} instead of {file_pattern}` All events are different. Most of them pass `{file_pattern}` (actually, a buffer name), but there are several exceptions.